# How to check if one list contains all elements of another list in linq to sql statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a mission table and want to pass a `List<int>` contains some personId to a search method and return missions that have all of these personIds(as DoctorId, driverId,NurseId,OperatorId). I tried these six ways :

```
using (MainDataContext context = new MainDataContext())
        {
            return context.Missions
                .Where(t => !personIds.Except(new List<int>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID}).Any())
}
```

2:

```
!personIds.Any(item => !(new List<int?>() {t.DoctorID, t.NurseID,t.OperatorID,t.DriverID}.Contains(item)))
```

3 :

```
!personIds.Any(item => t.DoctorID != item && t.NurseID != item && t.OperatorID != item && t.DriverID != item)
```

4 :

```
personIds.Intersect(new List<int>()  { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID}).Count() == personIds.Count()
```

5:

```
personIds.All(u => new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(u))
```

6:

```
personIds.All(p => p == t.DoctorID || p == t.NurseID || p == t.OperatorID || p == t.DriverID)
```

and all of these raise the same error :

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

the following code works but it's dirty and I hope there is a better way :

```
personIds.Count() == 0
                    || (personIds.Count() == 1 && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[0]))

                    || (personIds.Count() == 2 && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[0])
                        && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[1]))

                    || (personIds.Count() == 3 && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[0])
                        && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[1])
                        && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[2]))

                    || (personIds.Count() == 4 && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[0])
                        && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[1])
                        && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[2])
                        && new List<int?>() { t.DoctorID, t.NurseID, t.OperatorID, t.DriverID }.Contains(personIds[3]))
```

is there any way to check if a list contains all elements of another list in linq to sql?

Comment: Check if intesection length is equal to second list length.

Comment: Have you tried creating the list outside the query and then doing `personIds.All(id => idList.Contains(id))`

Comment: @PawełDyl I tried this, it raises same error

Comment: @juharr I have to do this in query, how can I create list of all person of a mission outside of the query?

Comment: @masoumehkarvar similar to how you do it in the query, just before it `var idList = new List<int?>() {t.DoctorID, t.NurseID,t.OperatorID,t.DriverID};`

Comment: @juharr  't' only means in the query

Comment: @masoumehkarvar Oh yeah, my bad.

Comment: So if `personIds` has more than 4 unique values then you wouldn't expect any results?  If so why not just get the potentially 4 unique values and see if any of those don't match any of the Mission ids?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd make sure all the ids are unique.  Then if there are more than 4 then you wouldn't want any results so there's no point in doing the query.  Finally you'd just iterate over the ids and do a `Where` that makes sure that each id is one of the mission ids.

```
using (MainDataContext context = new MainDataContext())
{
    var uniqueIds = personIds.Distinct().ToList();
    if(uniqueIds.Count > 4)
        return Enumerable.Empty<Mission>().AsQueryable();

    var result = context.Missions;
    foreach(int id in uniqueIds)
    {
        result = result.Where(t => id == t.DoctorID || 
                                   id == t.NurseID || 
                                   id == t.OperatorID ||
                                   id == t.DriverID);
    }
    return result;
}
```

My assumptions are that if you have more than 4 unique ids you'd want no results and if `personIds` is empty then you'd want all the missions.

Comment: you're right, personIds items are unique and less than 5 items. but my linq statement has many other filters and I cant use foreach like you do. I update my answer by your suggested way. it works but it's dirty.

Comment: @masoumehkarvar If you have other filters you can just do them first.  The `foreach` will dynamically add new filter that just get "Anded" on to the other ones.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't mark it as answer, it's  performance is very low .

Comment: @masoumehkarvar To improve performance, you'll likely need to add indexes on your id columns.